# How to rebuild plugins automatically in NativeScript project?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-cli

I try to develop a plugin for a sample NativeScript app (created with:
`tns create MyTnsApp --tsc`

I created a plugin for it with [nativescript-plugin-seed](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed/) (directory tree seen below).

I put a `console.log('Hello World!')` to the plugin and I called if from the main app. It works when I run it.

While the application is running and I change something in the plugin the cli detects it and it starts an incremental compilation. However, when I terminate running and run the app again the changes are not visible.
I have to remove the plugin with tns, and add it again.

**Is there a way to improve this process without removing/readding the plugin?**

Regards,
roncsak

---

```
├── app
│   ├── App_Resources
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── app.ts
│   ├── bundle-config.js
│   ├── bundle-config.ts
│   ├── main-page.js
│   ├── main-page.ts
│   ├── main-page.xml
│   ├── main-view-model.js
│   ├── main-view-model.ts
│   └── package.json
├── hooks
│   └── ...
├── node_modules
│   └── ...
├── package.json
├── platforms
│   └── ios
├── plugins
│   └── nativescript-myplugin
│       └── src
│           ├── index.js
│           ├── index.ts
│           ├── myplugin.js
│           ├── myplugin.ts
│           ├── package.json
│           ├── platforms
│           │   └── ios
│           └── tsconfig.json
│
└── tsconfig.json
```

./package.json

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.MyTnsApp",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "3.4.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-myplugin": "file:plugins/nativescript-myplugin/src",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.6.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

./plugins/nativescript-myplugin/src/package.json

```
{
  "name": "nativescript-myplugin",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Your awesome NativeScript plugin.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "nativescript": {
    "platforms": {
      "ios": "3.4.1"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tns-core-modules": "~3.4.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the Getting Started and Development sections in the README? They DO say how to develop continuously with changes being synced to your app - https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed/#getting-started

Comment: You are right, but those commands are valid if I use the demo application shipped with the nativescript-plugin-seed. I would like to find a solution where I do not have to to align package.json of the the main app for individual plugins such as mine. If NativeScript has a recommendation about the directory tree for apps with plugins, I think watching changes in plugins should rebuild the project as rebuild working if I change code in the main app...

Comment: You should npm link your plugin, and then develop your app using `tns run android/ios --syncAllFiles` which will also watch for changes from your linked node_modules.